# setTranslation is not working on onCreate()

Tags: android, android-view

`setTranslationY()` does not execute translation on a layout in `onCreate()`, while it's got no problem when used in a `setonTouchListener` or `setOnClickListener`.

I've also tried `animate().translationY()`. However the same exact problem appears.
I've tried to present the parts of my code in need to make the issue more clear. A layout is included in the activity. This layout contains another layout which it's height is used in translation measures.

Java codes:

```
View mainMenuIncluded, mainMenu ;
mainMenuIncluded = findViewById(R.id.main_menu_included);
mainMenu = mainMenuIncluded.findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_singer_list);
        mainMenuIncluded.setTranslationY(mainMenuIncluded.getY()-mainMenu.getHeight());
    }
```

The related xml part of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity">
<include
            layout="@layout/layout_pick_main_menu"
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_included"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The xml of the included layout (containig `mainMenu`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_gradient_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_menu_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_gradient_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: plz put your code here

Comment: @ShaluTD codes added . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate and move view only when it already drawn and measured.
Use:

Kotlin version:

```
yourView.post { 
    yourView.animate().translationY(/*value*/)            
}
```

Java version:

```java
yourView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourView.animate().translationY(/*value*/);
    }
};
```

for this

Comment: Yes. This was code from Kotlin. I add code in Java in answer. Please check

Comment: Nice to hear that :)

Comment: Thanks anyway! Could you explain why `post(Runnable runnable){}` is needed, please?

Comment: when you call view.post it causes the Runnable (body of lambda in case of Kotlin) to be added to the message queue (on the thread to which this handler is 
attached). When this runnable will be enqued, your view will be already drawn and measured. Try to see views width, height, left, right in onCreate during debug

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this part:

```
mainMenuIncluded.setTranslationY(mainMenuIncluded.getY()-mainMenu.getHeight());
```

with:

```
mainMenuIncluded.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainMenuIncluded.setTranslationY(mainMenuIncluded.getY() - mainMenu.getHeight());
    }
};
```